# How to get the current folder where code file located, using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

as Title.

I utilized Google App Script to copy an existing spreadsheet to a new one.  It was created at the root directory.  How can I create a spreadsheet at the current folder where the code file located?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination) method, you can pass the destination directory where you want the file to be created:

```
function leFunction(){

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId'); 
 var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId'); 
 DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(destFolder); 

}
```

Comment: Happy to help (: and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct.